# Android: WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON question

Tags: android, flags

Im using the following code to keep the screen on:

```
this.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

Is there any way to disable/remove the `FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON` later in the code? (I want the screen to fadeout normally).

Thanks!

Comment: you can simply clearFlags.. getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

Answer (score 29):

You could probably do something like this

```
this.getWindow().setFlags(this.getWindow().getFlags() & ~WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON)
```

Did you look at the API? There's also this method

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html#clearFlags%28int%29

```
this.getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

I have not tried this either yet.

I imagine this will work to check if the flag is set:

this.getWindow().getFlags() & WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON

Edit: As per the comments, apparently this is how you get the value of the flag.

```
this.getWindow().getAttributes().flags & WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON
```

There might be a method for that too, you should look at the API doc.

Comment: Hmm on the second "getWindow" eclipse tells me that "getWindow cannot be resolved or is not a field"

Comment: I meant getWindow(). But I'm not entirely certain the getFlags method works like that. I didn't actually pull up the api

Comment: 'this.getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);' works. Is there an easy way to check if the flag is active or not (if the app is in fullscreen mode)?

Comment: There is no getFlags() function in the Window class.

Comment: 'this.getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);' Worked great for me as well.  Thank you!

Comment: There is no `getFlags()` function, but you you can get them by calling `getAttributes().flags`

Comment: Thanks Jon! It worked well for me. Falmarri you might want to edit your answer as the getFlags() part is actually wrong.

Answer (score 2):

**Try this**

```
getWindow().clearFlags(android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

[Also read this](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock.html)