# Keep Screen Bright While In AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, screen-brightness

I'm using this code in my AsyncTask to make sure the screen stays bright while the AsyncTask runs:

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

However, I don't want the screen to be forced to be bright after the AsyncTask has ran.  How can I essentially 'undo' or 'turn off' that option?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your onPostExecute method in your AsyncTask call

```
getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4620983/android-windowmanager-layoutparams-flag-keep-screen-on-question) question for more help.