# getWindow() cannot resolve inside AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-studio, android-asynctask

I am trying to implement something inside `AsyncTask` like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7195423/keep-screen-bright-while-in-asynctask).

```
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    ...
    // prevent screen sleep
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
}


@Override
protected void onPostExecute(List<Result> results) {
    super.onPostExecute(results);
    getWindow().clearFlag (WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    ...
}
```

But I get the error "`Cannot resolve method getWindow()`" in Android Studio. What am I missing?

**Update**

The constructor of my AsyncTask is:

```
public MyTask(ProgressDialog pDlg) {
    progressDlgReference = new WeakReference<>(pDlg);
    progressDlg = progressDlgReference.get();
    context = progressDlg.getContext();
    ...
}
```

I try to cast `context` to `Activity` but got run-time error with `((Activity) context).getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);`?

Comment: runOnUIThread()
try using it

Comment: @ArmasCyndromic there is no reason to use `runOnUiThread()` with `AsyncTask` since it already provides methods to run code on the main `Thread`

Comment: @codeMagic true there are methods that is used to run code on main thread.
I believe runOnUiThread() is that method that can give access to main thread even form some of the background tasks on need e.g doInBackground() in async task.

Comment: @ArmasCyndromic true but I've seen it cause too many problems for folks which is unnecessary since `AsyncTask` was created to solve these issues. If you need to update the UI from `doInBackground()` before the task finishes, there is no reason to introduce more complicated and possibly introduce more bugs with that code when you can simply call `publishProgress()`. If the task is done, then obviously `onPostExecute()` will be called to update the UI.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you can see [from the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getWindow()) `getWindow()` is a method of `Activity`. And, since you aren't in an `Activity`, the method is not available.

So you need a reference to the `Activity` to recognize this method.

Now, I can't see much of your code but you can pass the `Context` from the `Activity` and cast that to reference the method.

So you would [pass the Context like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17218840/starting-a-new-activity-after-info-is-received-in-other-thread/17219161#17219161) then cast it to `Activity`

[This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7378644/how-to-call-getwindow-outside-an-activity-in-android) should give you a little more help

Comment: Thanks, I have try get `context` in my `AsyncTask`
        `context = progressDlg.getContext();` cast it in `onPreExecute` and `onPostExecute`, but get run-time error.

Comment: @TRX you aren't passing a `Context` to your `AsyncTask` so I suppose your `Context` variable is `null`. [See this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15409912/should-i-use-asynctask-class-inside-the-mainactivity-extending-activity/15409989#15409989) on passing it to your task constructor.

Answer (score 2):

`getWindow()` is a method available from your `Activity`.

This will be available to you via the ff:

- if your `AsyncTask` is within/inside your `Activity`.
- `getActivity().getWindow()`

Comment: My `AsyncTask` is not inside `Activity`, but a separate class, the caller is a `Fragment`

Comment: You can achieve this in different ways. For example, you can pass your `Activity` to your `AsyncTask` as per @codeMagic, and from there, you can call `yourActivity.getWindow()`.

Please remember that `getWindow()` method will only be accessible to you from your `Activity` or if you have reference to an `Activity`.

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
yourActivity.this.getWindow().clearFlag (WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

Here is a ref that can help you more:
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7378652/1263362)