# Re-enable status bar

Tags: android

I'm using this code to hide the top status bar

```
public static void removeNotificationBar(Activity activity) {
    if (activity != null) {
        activity.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    }
}
```

But it seems I need to enable it back on in some cases in my activity and I am unable ti figure out what flags to pass to the window to re-enable the status bar.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options to solve your problem:

**the first one:** is to [clear the flag](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html#clearFlags%28int%29), as described [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4621339/1638739) you can use:

```
activity.getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

---

**the second one:** as this flag is in the activity scope, you can rerun the activity without any animation so that the user won't be able to figure out that the activity is re-initiated:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
activity.startActivity(intent);
finish();
activity.overridePendingTransition(0, 0); // to restart the activity with No Animation
```

Comment: @AndreiBogdan you are so welcome, and I'm really happy I could help in solving your problem.